# rand() function not generating enough random

Tags: c++, opengl

I am working on an openGL project and my rand function is not giving me a big enough random range.
I am tasked with writing a diamond program to where one diamond is centered on the screen and 5 are randomly placed elsewhere on the screen. What is happening is my center diamond is where it is supposed to be and the other five are bunching with a small range of random left of center. I have included the function that draws the diamonds.

```
void myDisplay(void)
{
srand(time(0));

GLintPoint CenterPoint;
int const size = 20;

CenterPoint.x = screenWidth / 2;
CenterPoint.y = screenHeight / 2;

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

drawDiamond(CenterPoint, size);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    GLfloat x = rand() % 50 + 10;
    GLfloat y = rand() % 200 + 100;
    GLfloat size = rand() % 100;
    GLintPoint diam = {x,y};
    drawDiamond(diam, size);
}
```

If more code is needed, please let me know and I will edit. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can correct this? I have "toyed" with the numbers of the rand() function and really doesn't seem to do much. They still seem to bunch just at different points on the screen. I appreciate the help. Just in case anyone needs to know, I am creating this in VS2012.

Comment: This is a problem with most pseudo-random number generators. They are by nature very deterministic, and to make them appear "random" you have to supply a quality seed. If you spawn 3 or 4 processes at the same time using `time (NULL)` for the seed, they will generate the same sequence of events. You might consider re-seeding the RNG periodically, using a different seed (perhaps process id) or some combination of both. Also using modulus on `rand ()` actually hinders the quality of the results, you should cast to float and divide by `RAND_MAX` and scale this according to your desired range.

Comment: It would seem that you aren't trying to generate a full range of values either.  I would think something like `GLfloat x = rand() % (screenWidth - 20) + 10;` would be more appropriate and the same for the y value.  Unless your screen is 70x400 that would explain the clustering in the corner.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I was so hung on the repetitious seed and non-uniform modulo results, this totally fell off the radar. It is an *excellent* point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has no business being in this function:

```
srand(time(0));
```

This should be called *once* at the beginning of your program (a good place is just inside `main()`); and most-certainly not in your display routine. Once the seed is set, you should never do it again for your process unless you want to repeat a prior sequence (which by the looks of it, you don't).

That said, I would strongly advise using the functionality in [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that comes with your C++11 standard library. With it you can establish distributions (ex: [`uniform_int_distribution<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)) that will do much of your modulo work for you, and correctly account for the problems such things can encounter (Andon pointed out one regarding likeliness of certain numbers based on the modulus).

Spend some time with `<random>`. Its worth it. An example that uses the three ranges you're using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine rng(rd());

    // our distributions.        
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist1(50,60);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist2(200,300);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist3(0,100);

    for (int i=0;i<10;++i)
        std::cout << dist1(rng) << ',' << dist2(rng) << ',' << dist3(rng) << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output** (obviously varies).

```
58,292,70
56,233,41
57,273,98
52,204,8
50,284,43
51,292,48
53,220,42
54,281,64
50,290,51
53,220,7
```

Yeah, it really is just that simple. Like I said, that library is this cat's pajamas. There are *many* more things it offers, including random normal distributions, different engine backends, etc. I highly encourage you to check into it.

Answer (score 2):

As WhozCraig mentioned, seeding your random number generator with the time every time you call `myDisplay (...)` is a bad idea. This is because `time (NULL)` has a granularity of 1 second, and in real-time graphics you usually draw your scene more than one time per-second. Thus, you are repeating the same sequence of random numbers every time you call `myDisplay (...)` when less than 1 second has elapsed.

Also, using modulo arithmetic on a call to `rand (...)` adversely affects the quality of the returned values. This is because it changes the probability distribution for numbers occurring. The preferred technique should be to cast `rand (...)` to float and then divide by RAND_MAX, and then multiply this result by your desired range.

```
GLfloat x = rand() % 50 + 10; /* <-- Bad! */

/* Consider this instead */
GLfloat x = (GLfloat)rand () / RAND_MAX * 50.0f + 10.0f;
```

Although, come to think of it. Why are you using `GLfloat` for x and y if you are going to store them in an integer data structure 2 lines later?